# Force break <div/> across multiple pages when printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I am writing a JSP application that specializes in generating EDI Standard Documentation. Right now, I am having trouble formatting the output.

The following JSP snippet will generate a problematic PDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
    @page {
        size: 7in 9.25in;
        margin: 0.25in 0.25in 0.25in 0.25in;
    }

    p:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .main-container {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .main-container .row .left {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 29%;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .main-container .row .right {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 69%;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
                Label1:
            </div><div class="right">
                <% for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { %>
                    <p>First 10 lines will fit on the first page.</p>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
                Label2:
            </div><div class="right">
                <% for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) { %>
                    <p><%= i %>Test line goes here. Let's make a 1000.</p>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I open the JSP in Chrome and hit Print, the print preview shows the first `<div class="row">` on the first page, listing the 10 lines, but the second `<div class="row">` appears on the next page where it can fit in its whole.

I want the text to simply continue right where the previous `<div>` left off. I do not want the next `<div>` to be fit on the next page. Essentially, I want the browser to **stop avoiding** the page break.

So far, I've tried a variety of CSS properties, namely: page-break-before/after/inside set to a number of combinations of `auto/avoid/always/etc`. These solutions have not worked unfortunately. I tried rendering with flyingsaucer but couldn't find any solution there either. I really don't want to have to resort to calculating the distance manually as that is way beyond the scope of what was supposed to be a quick and dirty tool.

I've been trying to find a solution to this, but since the most common case is to do exactly what I want to avoid, it is difficult to fish out the answer (if there is one). Perhaps one of you knows a solid way of achieving this?